# How to convert a 2d vector into a set of vectors?

Tags: c++11, vector, set

I a 2d vector which I want to store in a set of vectors.
Like if I have a 2d vector like this:

vector<vector> v = {{0, 5}, {1, 2}, {0,2}, {0, 5}, {1,3}};
and I want a set of vectors in which those duplicate vectors are no longer present.
set<vector> s = {{0, 2}, {0,5}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}};

I have tried doing so like this but it isn't working:

```
int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> vect = {{0, 5}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 5}, {1, 3}};

    set<vector<int>> s;

    for(vector<int> temp : vect) {
        s.insert( temp.begin(), temp.end());
    }

    
    display(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me how to do it ?

Comment: "Isn't working" is too wide to get answered. Show error or expected and actual result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
for(vector<int> temp : vect) {
    s.insert( temp.begin(), temp.end());
}
```

What you meant to do is insert each vector into the set.   But instead you are inserting a range of integers (the content of the vector) into the set, and since the set contains vectors I think this will call the `vector(size_t size)` constructor which creates an empty vector of `size` elements each time.

Instead, try this:

```
s.insert(vect.begin(), vect.end());
```

That will insert all the vectors.  You can then simplify to:

```
set<vector<int>> s(vect.begin(), vect.end());
```

Which does the same thing during the initial construction of `s` instead of requiring a second step.